# How can I set a node to unschedulable status via the Kubernetes api?

Tags: kubernetes

I am attempting to emulate the behavior of `kubectl patch`.  I'm sending an HTTP PATCH with a json payload of the following:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Node",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "my-node-hostname"
    },
    "spec": {
        "unschedulable": true
    }
}
```

However, no matter how I seem to tweak this JSON, I keep getting a 415 and the following JSON status back:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "the server responded with the status code 415 but did not return more information",
  "details": {},
  "code": 415
}
```

Even with debug on kube-apiserver set to 1000, I get no feedback about why the payload is wrong!

Is there a particular format that one should use in the JSON payload sent via PATCH to enable this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a helpful member of the Kubernetes Slack channel mentioned I could get the payload from `kubectl patch` via the --verbose flag, it turns out that Kubernetes expects to get `"Content-Type: application/strategic-merge-patch+json"` when you are sending the PATCH payload.